# Angular and Stripe, Can't create Card token using $http, but can using CURL

Tags: angularjs, stripe-payments

First off, please forgive me if this is considered vague, this is my first time posting to Stack Exchange.

Hopefully, this is not a poorly formed question, I did give it some thought, though it assumes familiarity with CURL, Stripe and Angular.

On to the problem:

I am trying to recreate the results of a CURL to the Stripe API with Angular.js's $http and having some trouble doing so.

Using CURL, I am able to create a card token as follows:

```
curl -X POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens \
   -u MY_TEST_KEY: \
   -d "card[number]"=4242424242424242 \
   -d "card[exp_month]"=12 \
   -d "card[exp_year]"=2017 \
   -d "card[cvc]"=123
```

This gives me something like "tok_blahblahbcryptnonsense"

However, I cannot seem to translate this CURL into an Angular $http function, and I am getting back a status code 400, with the message "You must pass full card details to create a token."

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer MY_TEST_KEY'
    },
    params: {
       card: {
          "number": '4242424242424242', // I have tried this as
                                       // an integer and string
                                      // Stripe docs say string
          "exp_month": 12,
          "exp_year": 2017,

          "cvc": '123'    // I have tried this as
                         // an integer and string
                        // Stripe docs don't specify but I think string
       }
    }
  }).then(function(success){
      console.log('success ', success)
  }, function(error){
      console.log('error ', error) // gets here, this is where the message is
  })
```

As far as my understanding goes, this is totally possible. All I need is to create a token for said card. It is getting late and it might be a totally obvious solution and I'm too tired.

Comment: Open the dev tools of your browser, and click on the network tab. Then send your request. Then look at the body of the request in the network tab. What does it look like?

Comment: Wow, I'm already embarrassed, should have been way more specific. I'm running this code in ionic, on emulated iPhone 5s - iOS 9.2 with live reload and console enabled. The code itself is just angular, so I thought to pose the question that way. I guess I'll throw this into a different angular project and check it out quickly.

Comment: @SamuelPolicar: Just a heads up, for PCI compliance reasons, you should *not* be making the raw HTTP request yourself. You should use Stripe Checkout or Stripe.js instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the Stripe API also accepts JSON, but what you're sending in your curl command is not JSON. It's form data.

Moreover, `params` is used to pass data in the query string. You want this data in the POST body.

The correct code should be:

```
var myData = {
  card: {
    "number": '4242424242424242', 
    "exp_month": 12,
    "exp_year": 2017,
    "cvc": '123'
  }
};
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer MY_TEST_KEY',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(myData),
});
```

Comment: Thank you JB, that $httpParamSerializerJQLike and data key were what was missing. It's odd, certain POST requests for Stripe work with x-www-form-urlencoded using the params key and no $httpParamSerializerJQLike. That really messed up my train of thought, not to mention coding this project for the last 10 straight. I can finally sleep.