# stripe connect identity verification using angular http post

Tags: angular, post, stripe-payments

I am using the ng-file-upload directive to send a image file to my angular controller. https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Inside my angular controller I am trying to translate this curl post from the stripe API docs into a http post. https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication

```
curl https://files.stripe.com/v1/files \
   -u {PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY}: \
   -H "Stripe-Account: {CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}" \
   -F purpose=identity_document \
   -F file="@/path/to/a/file"
```

My code:

```
Upload.upload({
   url: "https://files.stripe.com/v1/files",
   method: "POST",
   headers: {
     "Authorization": "Bearer SK_Test_key",
     "Stripe-Account": "connected_acct_id",
      },
   data: {
     "purpose": "identity_document",
     file: file
    }
})...
```

this returns a 401 invalid api key provided

I searched around stackoverflow and found a few stripe http post examples not using connect [Angular and Stripe, Can't create Card token using $http, but can using CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953964/angular-and-stripe-cant-create-card-token-using-http-but-can-using-curl)
, I feel my error comes from formatting.

Reading the curl documentation I know -F stands for "form" and -H is for "headers", -u is for "user", I've tried sending "user": "sk_test_key" outside of headers and inside data with no luck, same with file

Comment: You should never place your secret key anywhere in your client side code because it could be abused. You might find this helpful though to see a working client-side file upload example (it's vanilla js but could easily be adapted in your case https://jsfiddle.net/thorstripe/bdm3j2rn/)

Comment: I understand the security risk but am more focused on the formatting of my request, I will try taking your example and seeing what I can figure out. Thanks again for your help!